# C# / apsx.net - Dynamically created button doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, button, buttonclick, preinit

Here is my problem:  I had dynamically created some buttons in my page (in the Page_PreInit method), all linked to the same event handler. But those buttons don't fire the event when I click on them... Can someone help me?

Here is some of my code:

Button creation (on a foreach loop on the Page_PreInit method):

```
Button b = new Button();
field.Controls.Add(b);

b.Text = "Download";
b.ID = tmp_out[type] as String;
b.Click += new EventHandler(Download_Click);
```

The OnClick method:

```
private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //doing some stuff
}
```

Comment: b.Click += new EventHandler(Download_Click); but your method signature is void Download_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)

Comment: Sorry, Paste the wrong method, message edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem.

The ids of the buttons was containing some '\'. I just removed those '\' and it works just fine.

Thanks all for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic controls must be added during Page PreInit or Init, not on load.  This is because of page lifecycle and viewstate loading... so try that first to see if that solves the problem.

Also, I believe I read that it's best to order your code this way:

```
Button b = new Button();
field.Controls.Add(b);

b.Text = "Download";
b.ID = tmp_out[type] as String;
b.Click += new EventHandler(Download_Click);
```

Adding the control first to the inner collection, then changing it's properties.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that and I'll let you know if that fix my issue.

Comment: So i'm trying to add my code on the PreInit method but I have some issues ... I'm creating a table with many button, but since I put my code in the PreInit method, my table is created twice. And now my buttons do stuff, they raise an execption saying that there IDs aren't unique (but when inspecting with firebug, all are differents :s)

Comment: Well I'd recommend having a static table by adding the <asp:Table /> to the page, but just dynamically building the rows.  That will assist with that problem.

Comment: Double table and exception issues fixed (I was just biding two times the PreInit method), but my buttons still won't fire the event ...

Comment: I still can't figure my buttons aren't firing the event... Did you have any other suggestions? I'm really stuck here ...

Answer (score 0):

your event handler statement is

```
b.Click += new EventHandler(Download_Click);
```

but your method is

```
private void Download_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
```

are you sure its the right method to be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Should not be like this?

```
...
b.Click += new EventHandler(Download_Command);
...

private void Download_Command(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //doing some stuff
}
```